# Extraction of data

Tags: cloud

I am trying to extract monthly mean of a vertical profile variable mass mixing ratio(MMR) from a netcdf file  for the duration 2000-2003 for a region (longitude -45W to 10E and latitude 30-40E)and a point (lat=37 deg, lon=-40) and also for entire geographical region.
Task:

1. Extract monthly MMR at 400-450, 450-500,500-550,550-600 hpa for the region and the point during 2000-2003. For instance, at 400 hPa get (latitude,longitude,MMR as raster layer)
2. Extract monthly ozone MMR at between two pressure levels as raster format.

```
library(ncdf4)
nc = nc_open("E:/ERA5/ERA_2000_2003.nc")
lat=ncvar_get (nc,"latitude") ; lon=ncvar_get(nc,"longitude")
t = ncvar_get(nc, "time")
pres = ncvar_get(nc, "level")
length(lat); length(lon);length(time);length(pres)
t <- as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 00:00")+as.difftime(t,units="hours")
x <- c(400, 450, 500, 550, 600) 

#I want ozone for longitude -45W to 10E and latitude (30-40E) at pressure level 500 
#for all years (12months*4 yrs= 48 months) 

oz = ncvar_get(nc,'o3',start=c(1,1,1,1),count=c(100,-1,x[3],-1))
lonIdx <- which( lon >= -40 & lon <= 10.00);
latIdx <- which( lat >= 30.00 & lat <= 45.00)
```

I get the following error:

```
1. Error: cannot allocate vector of size 558.5 Mb
```

```
oz = ncvar_get(nc,'o3',start=c(lonIdx,latIdx,1,1),count=c(length(lonIdx),length(latIdx),x[1),-1))
```

```
# and sometimes error messages like
2.Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
 Error: 
variable has 4 dims, but start has 264 entries.  They must match!

3. Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset, : Error: variable has 4 dims, but start has 324 entries.  They must match!
Traceback:

1. ncvar_get(nc, "o3", start = c(lonIdx, latIdx, 1, 1), count = c(length(lonIdx), 
 .     length(latIdx), -1, -1))
2. ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset, 
 .     scaleFact, start = start, count = count, verbose = verbose, 
 .     signedbyte = signedbyte, collapse_degen = collapse_degen, 
 .     raw_datavals = raw_datavals)
3. stop(paste("Error: variable has", ndims, "dims, but start has", 
 .     length(start), "entries.  They must match!"))
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank You

[image: Data Description]

Comment: "1. Error: cannot allocate vector of size 558.5 Mb" means you must be running out of RAM. Try closing any other applications etc.

Comment: Only RStudio was open: I tried after closing chrome too. I get this "Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_int: NetCDF: Start+count exceeds dimension bound
Var: o3  Ndims: 4   Start: 0,0,0,0 Count: 48,400,35,100
Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  C function Rsx_nc4_get_var_int returned error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options to extract the subset of interest from the netcdf object are 1) using the `ncvar_get` function with `start` and `count` defined, or 2) using `ncvar_get` to extract the entire array and then using standard `base R` array indexing to subset. I'm not exactly sure how to calculate MMR, so I am showing how to extract o3 values and do some basic summarization. If this doesn't achieve the two tasks specifically, hopefully it is has enough hints to get you started.

Read in the data

```
library(ncdf4)

# read file 
nc <- nc_open("ERA5_2000_03.nc")

# extract variable levels
lat <- ncvar_get (nc, "latitude")
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "longitude")
t <- ncvar_get(nc, "time")
t <- as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 00:00") + as.difftime(t, units = "hours")
pres <- ncvar_get(nc, "level")
```

Define the indices of the region of interest

```
lonIdx <- which(lon >= -40 & lon <= 10)
latIdx <- which(lat >= 30 & lat <= 45)
presIdx <- which(pres >= 475 & pres <= 525) # subset to only 500
tIdx <- which(t == t) # i.e., no subset of t
```

Extract `o3` for all month and pressure levels

```
# Option 1 -- use ncvar_get()
extract1 <- ncvar_get(nc,
                      'o3',
                      start = c(lonIdx[1],latIdx[1], presIdx[1], tIdx[1]),
                      count = c(length(lonIdx),length(latIdx),length(presIdx), length(tIdx)))


# Option 2 -- subset using array indexing
o3 <- ncvar_get(nc,'o3')
extract2 <- o3[lonIdx, latIdx, presIdx, ]


# Check the outputs are identical
identical(extract1, extract2)
#>TRUE
```

Optionally, you can also name the array dimensions, which is helpful for making results intuitive

```
# Name the array dimensions
dimnames(o3) <- list('lon' = lon, 
                     'lat' = lat,
                     'pres' = pres,
                     'time' = as.character(as.Date(t)))

extract3 <- o3[lonIdx,latIdx, , ]

# Monthly mean for each level of pres across the entire region of interest
apply(extract3, c('pres', 'time'), mean)
#       time
# pres    2000-01-01   2000-02-01   2000-03-01
#   400 8.627874e-08 8.303606e-08 9.857230e-08
#   450 7.911534e-08 7.790138e-08 9.043681e-08
#   500 7.421088e-08 7.398450e-08 8.510393e-08
#   550 7.074213e-08 7.102885e-08 8.128490e-08
#   600 6.817185e-08 6.840323e-08 7.853805e-08
#   ...

# o3 levels at a specific long/lat
o3['-40', '37', ,]
#       time
# pres    2000-01-01   2000-02-01   2000-03-01
#   400 8.160814e-08 8.172732e-08 1.006738e-07
#   450 7.688993e-08 7.681632e-08 9.276743e-08
#   500 7.274836e-08 7.514602e-08 8.791778e-08
#   550 6.989851e-08 7.359140e-08 8.330298e-08
#   600 6.867163e-08 7.110260e-08 8.087377e-08
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... I just want to clear a few doubts. Why is range of pressure "presIdx <- which(pres >= 475 & pres <= 525)" when the pressure levels are 400 450 500 550 600? Additionally, I tried with #option 1 on other similar dataset, and I get the following error "Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  Error: variable has 4 dims, but start has 8 entries.  They must match!". Can you please elaborate on #option 1

Comment: Right, sorry I wasn't more clear about that. I added `presIdx` just to give an example of how to use it. In the above code `presIdx` only has one value (500). The `start` values in option 1 would be more robust if I had written `presIdx[1]`. The `start` values represent the index where you begin your subset, and `count` represents the length along the index of interest. I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: For example if you had a 2D 10x10 matrix, and you wanted to subset row 2-8 and col 4-7, you would need `start = c(2, 4)` and `count = c(7, 4)`.

Comment: Or as written above it would be something along the lines of `ridx <- 2:8; cidx <- 4:7` then `start = c(ridx[1], cidx[1])` and `count = c(length(ridx), length(cidx))`

Comment: Very well understood. Thanks for the much needed help.