# Extracting data from Netcdf using defined spatial polygon

Tags: r, polygon, netcdf, shapefile, netcdf4

I followed the following example to extract data from Netcdf [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591473/extraction-of-data/69233237#69233237). It went all good but the problem I faced is to extract the data by spatial polygon (shapefiles). How do I extract the data (o3) using polygon shapefiles instead of lat/lon box?

Instead of defining the region `lonIdx <- which(lon >= -40 & lon <= 10) latIdx <- which(lat >= 30 & lat <= 45)` I want to use spatial polygon.